# How to use fully qualified acronyms

Tags: acronyms

Which is proper/acceptable?

Take for instance this sentence:

> We would like to use IBM machines.

Now consider that I needed to fully qualify IBM... How do I make this not read strangely?

> We would like to use IBM (International Business Machines) machines.

or

> We would like to use International Business Machines (IBM) machines.

(Please note that IBM is not the real acronym but it's similar to what I need to pull off)

**EDIT:**

I should add that part of my question is that if it's incorrect or less correct to put [Fully qualified name] (Acronym) or [Acronym] (Fully qualified name)

Comment: In this instance, you might want to use "IBM computers" instead of "IBM machines" to eliminate the redundancy.

Comment: It sounds find as is...what's the problem?

Comment: This is a translation situation... My ability to "deviate" is limited... The client doesn't want something dumb sounding, so if I could make this verbiage not be off-putting, it would be ideal... Deviation is a last option...

Comment: @Rikon If this is a translation, and you've already given us some sentences that are fine, what is the issue? They don't sound "dumb".

Comment: @simchona: I edited and qualified my original question asking to the correctness of putting one before the other... I wasn't direct enough with my original question. Btw, thanks for the help!

Comment: I saw your edit--please see my answer.

Comment: @rikon RAS Syndrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using acronyms in writing, the [APA Style Guide](http://thewritedirection.net/drpaper/help/05-07-apastyle.htm) recommends:

> When you do use abbreviations, always give the full name the first time you use it: The Modern Humanities Research Association (MHRA) -- unless it is commonly used as a word (AIDs, IQ, URL). Write out the complete name, and then give the abbreviation you will use (as illustrated above), unless the abbreviation is widely recognized (CIA).

IBM is a fairly well-recognized acronym. If you must write out the fully qualified name, however, then the most proper sentence would be:

> We would like to use International Business Machines (IBM) machines.

As @Randolf mentioned, though, you might want to avoid calling them "IBM machines" because of the redundancy.

Comment: To Randolf's point, I agree and will avoid it if I can... It's an odd acronym.  Absolutely perfect!